# Specify the exact size of matplotlib figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm having a hard time to make some of my figures in my paper aligned appropriately.

Here is the problem. I have two figures that I want to use the same x-axis. I plot two figures separately and include them as two subfigures in Latex. The problem with this: the yticklabels of the second graph take more room, which makes it look smaller than the first graph.

[image]

I specified the figsize as the same using the following code

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
```

But obviously when other things like titles, labels, tick labels take more space, the "main plot" appears smaller, making two subfigures misaligned. Is there any way to specify the size of the "main plot" ignoring other labels, titles, etc.?

P.S.: I didn't use matplotlib's subplots function because I noticed a bug in pandas or matplotlib: whenever I use an inset axis, the xlabel and xticklabels will not show. So I have to get around this by plotting two figures respectively and include them as two subfigures in latex.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `left` value of `fig.subplots_adjust` to a constant for both plots, the left edges should be in the same place, e.g.:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0.12) # you might need to adjust 0.12 to your needs
```

Put that in your scripts for both your figures and that should align them both nicely.

Comment: Well, I tried, but this does not solve the problem. I'm not using plt.subplots to plot those subfigures. I have to generate those figures first and align them using Latex.

Comment: you say in the question that you use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))` to specify the figure size...

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear. I did use plt.subplots() to specify the figure size, but that was just for one subfigure. I use one plt.subplots() for each of the subfigure and try to combine them in Latex. As shown in the image, the second subfigure (the part within the axes) appears smaller than the first one. Using fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0.12) still gives the same results.

Answer (score 1):

When I am faced with this situation, I simply hard code the axes placement on the figure, then things will line up...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes([0.15, 0.65, 0.8, 0.3])
ax.plot(range(100), range(100))

ax2 = plt.axes([0.15, 0.15, 0.8, 0.3])
ax2.plot(range(100), range(10000, 110000,  1000))
```

[image]